# How to store selections in comboboxes to variables in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following UserForm:

[image]

Where a user selects from the dropdown their name and age, this in MyForm(Code)

```
Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()

   ' Call MainValuesInForm 'use this if you want to trigger after selection of the value

End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox3_Change()
    
  '  Call MainValuesInForm 'use this if you want to trigger after selection of the value

End Sub

Private Sub MainValuesInForm()
    
    Dim Name As String
    Dim Age As String
    
    Name = Me.ComboBox2.value
    Age = Me.ComboBox3.value
    
    ActiveCell.value = Name & " " & Age
    
End Sub

Private Sub SubmitButton_Click()
    
    Call MainValuesInForm 'or use this if you want to trigger by means of the 'Submit' (or Insert) button
    
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    With Me.ComboBox2
        .Clear
        .AddItem "Joe"
        .AddItem "Jack"
        .AddItem "Dan"
     
    End With
    
    With Me.ComboBox3
        .Clear
        .AddItem "30"
        .AddItem "40"
        .AddItem "50"
    End With
End Sub
```

To be clear, the user would have an activecell then run the macro.
Ideally, the user would make a selection in the two comboboxes, press insert, the concatenation is written to the activecell. Then once written the form remains open and selection in the comboxes goes to blank so the user can continue inserting data into different activecells

I'm trying to take the selection from the two comboboxes in the form and then concatenate these values and place them in the activecell

Comment: `ActiveCell.Value = Name & " " & Age`

Comment: Thanks, but how do I store the selection in the two boxes into the variables Name and Age?

Comment: In the formula to be pasted in the cell you use references 'Name' & 'Age' yet these do not exist in the XL sheet, they exist -only- in the VBA module. So the formula `ActiveCell.Formula = "=concatenate(Name, Age)"` will give you an error as neither `Name` nor `Age` exist as named ranges in the sheet. So above answer by @braX which shoudl solve your issue.

Comment: The `MainValues` method is in a module whereas the two ComboBoxes are in a form. You can only transfer the values from the form to the module method by calling a method in the module with the value of the combobox as a parameter? Or, move the `MainValues` method to the form and call that after the ComboBoxes have changed?

Comment: `Name = Me.Combobox2.Value`

Comment: I can move the MainValues sub to the MyForm if that makes a solution easier to reach. When adding ```Name = Me.ComboBox2.value``` into Module1 however, i get a compilation error for misuse of Me

Comment: That is because the Module has no `Me` object, that would only be applicable to a form

Comment: Also should i be doing anything to the Submit button in order to execute the writing to the activecell?

Comment: @mtholen Ok, ignroe the module file, ill place the MainValues sub within the MyForm file

Comment: Updated below answer to reflect the use of the 'Submit' button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()

    Call MainValuesInForm 'use this if you want to trigger after selection of the value

End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox3_Change()
    
    Call MainValuesInForm 'use this if you want to trigger after selection of the value

End Sub

Private Sub MainValuesInForm()
    
    Dim Name As String
    Dim Age As String
    
    Name = Me.ComboBox2.Value
    Age = Me.ComboBox3.Value
    
    ActiveCell.Value = Name & " " & Age
    
End Sub

Private Sub SubmitButton_Click()
    
    Call MainValuesInForm 'or use this if you want to trigger by means of the 'Submit' (or Insert) button
    
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    With Me.ComboBox2
        .Clear
        .AddItem "Joe"
        .AddItem "Jack"
        .AddItem "Dan"
     
    End With
    
    With Me.ComboBox3
        .Clear
        .AddItem "30"
        .AddItem "40"
        .AddItem "50"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This pretty much does exactly what i want. Is there a way to only write the concatenation to the cell when the submit button is pressed ?

Comment: yes, remove the `Call MainValuesInForm` for each of the ComboBoxes...

Comment: When i comment out the ```Call MainValuesInForm``` in the two subs at the top for both comboboxes, no data is written to the activecell. It just stalls. Ideally, i'd make a selection in the two comboboxes, press submit, the concatenation is written to the activecell. Then once written the form remains open and selection in the comboxes go to blank so the user can continue inserting data into different activecells

Comment: Did you add the `Call MainValuesInForm` for your insert button `_Click()` event?

Comment: Yes, ill update the question,

Comment: I think you have now updated the question and have pasted working code to your question...? That might make others wonder what the issue is... 

If you want the form to stay open while the user selects a new `ActiveCell`, you would have to start the form as `vbModeless` or set the `ShowModal` property to `false`

Comment: Is the 'Name' of your button `SubmitButton` ??? If not then set it to that or change the `SubmitButton_Click()` to `CommandButton1_Click()` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249805/discussion-between-mtholen-and-daniel-stafford).